# Styling the action bar title text and icons

Tags: menu, colors, styles, android-actionbar, title

i am having a problem with this line in code inside theme.xml
@color/actionbar_text

it says there is no actionbar_text inside color dir. Where is this color directory anyway?
and which format should actionbar_text should be like for icons we do

android:icon="@drawable/action_search" where action_search is of png format

plz help